# Regex remove word from a specific string, and isolate the number

Tags: regex, string

I have tried to remove a the "unidade(s)" word in the following string

2 unidade(s)
10 unidade(s)
99 unidade(s)

But i could find a way using regex.

Does anybody know how to do it ?

Comment: Do you want to capture **all** numbers in the string, but remove all unidade(s)?

Answer (score -1):

In what language do you need this? Here's how you do it in JavaScript:

```
"2 unidade(s) 10 unidade(s) 99 unidade(s)".replace(/unidade(\(s\))?/g, "");

// Resulting string is "2  10  99 "
```

Comment: The problem is the number. I could have thousands of random numbers on the beggining of the sentence.

Comment: And the objective is always to remain with the number and erase the unidade(s)